# android application to send email runs on wifi but not on WAP

Tags: android, email

I have this application that accesses the internet to send an email in a background service. I added references and libraries for `javax.mail` and it is working fine using the WiFi.

in my service i have a function that tests internet connection. when using wap it shows that internet connection is available but when it goes through the `sendEmail` function, it doesn't really send the email although it did work when i tried it on WiFi.

Trying to troubleshoot it, i did another application that makes a HTTP get request but the same thing happened. the test internet function returned an available internet connection on wap but didn't get the HTTP request. it worked on WiFi.

i also tried to use the `ConnectivityManager` and set the default connection to `TYPE_MOBILE`, but it always gives me an error which is that the application needs the permission to `CHANGE_SECURE_SETTINGS` which i already added to the `AndroidManifest`.

how can i make my application run on WAP? should i be using WAP push messages, which honestly i have no idea about and didn't find any documentations about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, making some more research and contacting my provider, i found out that WAP is used only for browsing. applications usually can't use WAP.

Instead, they can use the GPRS. At least this is the case in lebanon, I'm not sure about other countries and other providers.

The application seems to work fine on GPRS.

Hope I've helped :D